# Finding the standard deviation of a list of deviations/elements

Tags: math, statistics, standard-deviation

I have a list of sets and some basic statistics for each one (number of items, min, max, mean, stddev). I would like to calculate the same statistics for all of the sets combined. Calculating the total count, min max and mean is easy, but I'm unsure how to calculate the total standard deviation.

The data looks like this:

```
Count        Max      Min      Mean      Stddev
1,027,671    781      68       57.8      32.79
  839,473    552      54       61.3      48.53
3,012,102    890      41       64.9      41.92
```

Generating the statistics for all of the sets together:

```
4,879,246    890      41       62.8      ???
```

Comment: Each set is calculated on a separate machine. I'd have to send all of that data over the network, which is not acceptable in my application.

Comment: You'd only need to send the three count, sum, and sum squared of summary information to compute the count/mean/standard deviation.  sum of squares is just a more computationally friendly statistic than the standard dev because it is combines through addition.  They have a bijective connection, if you know the count, sum, and std dev, you can get the count, sum and sum squares, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm going to use that. If you want you can submit it as as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are writing the code that maintains the distribution, and not just consuming some data that already has the standard deviation computed.  The standard dev isn't a really natural parameter to maintain for a computer.  Instead, You should maintain the number of items, the sum, and the sum of the items squared, and then you easily compute the mean and standard deviation the distribution from those 3 pieces of raw information. I use this strategy in this code here.  The add operation supports merging two distributions.  Notice how simple its implementation is. http://github.com/rrenaud/dominionstats/blob/master/stats.py#L17.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to calculate this exactly from the data you have. The problem is that the standard deviation depends on the mean of the combined data set which isn't necessarily the same as the individual means, and also on the distances of each point from that mean to which you have no exact (but maybe approximate) access.

Comment: this is wrong.  you can compute the mean of the combined data either via a count weighted sum of the individual means, or perhaps more clearly, by getting the sum and counts of the individual distributions from the sum and and means, and then crunching the combined count and sum into the combined mean.  A similar argument holds for the std dev, but it requires a little bit more algebra.

Comment: @rrenaud: I know it is easy to get the new mean, and I am curious to see your exact solution for the std. deviation with the information he has available.